# How to use Namespaced Sessions in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to use symfony2 sessions.I do this

```
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $session->set('token','value');
```

This works. But i want to use namespace in session. Documentation says

```
    class NamespacedAttributeBag
```

provides that feature but i cannot figure out how to implement it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just open your config.yml and after imports add:

```
parameters:
    session.attribute_bag.class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\NamespacedAttributeBag
```

It looks like this:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }

parameters:
    session.attribute_bag.class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\NamespacedAttributeBag

framework:
# ...
```

Comment: FYI: this won't work in Symfony 3, since they ripped out all of these class parameters.

Answer (score 9):

You should redefine session service and also define service for your attribute bag (if you'll check default implementation of `session.attribute_bag` you'll see that this service has only class attribute).

And inject your new service to redefined session service into there

```
services:
    session:
        class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session
        arguments:
            - @session.storage
            - @your.session.attribute_bag #service id is defined below
            - @session.flash_bag

    your.session.attribute_bag:
        class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\NamespacedAttributeBag
```

Comment: wow -- the docs really shouldn't even mention the NamespacedAttributeBag without going into more detail about how to use it. after banging my head against $session->registerBag() i'm glad to find this solution!

Comment: This helped alot but why isn`t the attribute consistant. I set some properties and next function call they are back to the default?

Comment: You shouldn't redefine services like that. You should alter the container in a compiler pass or overwrite the parameter in config.

Comment: EDIT: This is one of the only ways to do this in Symfony 3...or use a compiler pass.

Comment: The doc is not clear about this, thanks I was totally stuck. I don't understand why it is not the default implementation

Answer (score 4):

Because it's also possible to use the HTTPFoundation Component outside of Symfony2, the way to implement NamespacedUserBags is as follows:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\NamespacedAttributeBag;

$session = new Session();

//first bag
$myAttributeBag = new NamespacedAttributeBag('<your_storage_key_1>');
$myAttributeBag->setName('<your_tag_name_1>');
$session->registerBag($myAttributeBag);

//second bag
$myAttributeBag = new NamespacedAttributeBag('<your_storage_key_2>');
$myAttributeBag->setName('<your_tag_name_2>');
$session->registerBag($myAttributeBag);

$session->start();
```

Register as many bags as you want, but make sure to do this before you start the session. Now you can switch between bags using getBag():

```
$activeBag = $session->getBag('<your_tag_name>');
```

and access the namespaced bag with the typical methods :

```
$activeBag->set('tokens/a', 'adsf82983asd');
$activeBag->set('tokens/b', 'daslfl232l3k');

print_r($activeBag->get('tokens'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Symfony 3, the override of `session.attribute_bag.class` parameter doesn't work anymore.

The solution I applied after pulling my hair for a few time is using a compiler pass to override the `session.attribute_bag` service class.

I did it in the Kernel directly, but an external compiler pass would work the same way.

**SF4 Kernel**

```
<?php
// src/Kernel.php
namespace App;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\NamespacedAttributeBag;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    // ...

    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->getDefinition('session.attribute_bag')->setClass(NamespacedAttributeBag::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Symfony 4 (and Flex), use the following configuration to use `NamespacedAttributeBag`:

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
  session.attribute_bag: 
    class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\NamespacedAttributeBag
  # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update: Namespaced Sessions were removed in Symfony 6.0**

See https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/session.html#basic-usage

> The `NamespacedAttributeBag` class is deprecated since Symfony 5.3. If you need this feature, you will have to implement the class yourself.