# Symfony2: store and retrieve array in session

Tags: php, session, symfony, session-variables

I am new to symfony2 & using Symfony 2.5. I am following official Symfony documentation for guidance on session. To store and retrive an array from session, I am following [this official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html#attributes).

**Problem Background**

When user logs in and enters a website from front page, I start a new session, and store information using following code.

```
$sessionData = array(
                    'unit' => $unit,
                    'client' => $client,
                    'group' => $group,
                );
$session = new Session();
$session->set('fw', $sessionData);
```

When I `print_r` the session info, it gives me following output, which is as expected.

```
Array
    (
        [fw] => Array
            (
                [unit] => shoes
                [client] => nike
                [group] => north
            )
    )
```

**Problem 1**

Now when I want to add further data to this array, I follow the same symfony documentation given here http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html#attributes
and do the following.

`$this->get("session")->set('fw/storeid', $storeid);`

As per documentation my new store id detail should be stored in session as a key=>value pair inside the FW array. However, it saves it as it is. When I `print_r` , this is the output I get.

```
Array
    (
        [fw] => Array
            (
                [unit] => shoes
                [client] => bata
                [group] => north
            )
        [fw/storeid] => abc1
    )
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there a different way to store data in array in session?

**Problem 2**

From the above session, when I want to fetch some data, I do exactly as the docs says. `$this->get("session")->get('fw/unit');` . However, this gives me undefined index error. Once again, What is the correct way to fetch data from array within a session?

---

Are there any mode detailed examples available anywhere?

---

As a workaround I currently do it as follows , (which is exactly docs says we can avoid):

`$sessiondata = $this->get("session")->get('fw');
    $sessiondata['storeid'] = $storeid;
    $this->get("session")->set('fw', $sessiondata);`

Comment: Check the beginning of the chapter once again - you presumably have session initialized with `AttributeBag` (which is default)

Comment: Thanks @zerkms. How can I change from `AttributeBag` to `NamespacedAttributeBag` ? Moreover, in the same section, API details of `Attributebag` are given, but not that of `NamespacedAttributeBag`. Are they different ?

Comment: I've just put `symfony2 NamespacedAttributeBag` into the google and the first result is the answer. Why don't you try to solve your issue first before asking?

Comment: You are reading the low level session component documentation.  Start a bit higher up.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#index-12 to see how to use the session in the framework.  Hint: new Session(); is not going to help.

Comment: @zerkms Thanks, I should have read. I know this is not part of question, but when I try to use `NamespacedAttributeBag` with `PdoSession` , I get following Fatal Error: ` Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException' with message 'The service "session.handler.pdo" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "pdo.db_options".`  If you have time and if you can guide, it would be great.

Comment: Plz disregard my last comment. I followed http://stackoverflow.com/a/12279483/2337895 answer to solve it.